# any way to get a window handle by its title using win32 api?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

so the main problem is i need to use the SetPixel command to draw pixels on a specific window . lets say cmd . i do need the window handler and i dont know anyway to access the HWND of a window I didnt create .
anyway to do this ? 
or anyway to get an array of HWND's for a pid ? and THEN check them to match the specific title ?

many thanks in advance

PS : i found a couple of similar questions here . please note i want an answer using bare win32api since im using python and not .net .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you want [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the specified strings.

...

> If lpClassName is NULL, it finds any window whose title matches the lpWindowName parameter.